# Display data for a field but update data for a different field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radgrid

I'm modifying an old application. Because the application has changed over the years, we have two fields that we now want to effectively be the same. Once upon a time, we were using the `Email` field to store the login ID for the user. At some later time, we created a `Username` field, which is usually null.

We have an awful lot (at least a couple dozen) of stored procedures that return the `Email` field for the username, but only a few that *update* the database with information, including the login information. We can synchronize the two fields.

**I want to display the `Email` field in my grid, and update using the `Username` field.** Is this possible?

Here is the relevant code:

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True" Width="97%" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" 
            AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1" ShowStatusBar="True" PageSize="15"
            Skin="Telerik" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"></PagerStyle>
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="UserID" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"  CommandItemDisplay="Top" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand">
                <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToCsvButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false"></CommandItemSettings>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email" FilterControlAltText="Filter Login column" HeaderText="Login" SortExpression="Username" UniqueName="Username" FilterControlWidth="70px">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TasksConnectionString %>" ID="SQLDataSource1"
        runat="server" SelectCommand="GetScannerUsers" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="UpdateScannerUsers" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="AddScannerUsers" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="DeleteUser" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Note that I have tried to use the `DataField` and `UniqueName` properties to try to display data for `Email` yet access the `Username` field for updates. This isn't working, as I find the `UpdateScannerUsers` stored procedure is receiving `NULL` for the `Username` parameter value. I also find it's adding the `Email` parameter to the end of the stored procedure call.

Not relevant to the current problem, but we eventually use the `Email` field in the future to actually store an email address. It was probably storing the user ID because both email and username ought to be unique within the database.

Comment: So are you saying you want to update `Username` to equal the record's `Email` value? If so, this sounds like something you want to do on the database with a simple UPDATE statement. BTW, what is your Primary Key on the users table in the database?

Comment: Yes, and we will run that update statement. The primary key is UserID, which is unique in the database. But if we want to keep them in sync we must edit only the four stored procedures that insert and update, instead of all 52 stored procedures that use `Email` when they ought to use `Username`, so that pages that retrieve information can continue to use `Email`.

Comment: I suppose I can use code-behind to manually issue an UpdateCommand, and if I can't get it to work just client-side, then I'll have to do that.

Comment: @HardCode I just noticed I didn't tag you with my previous comments. I implemented server-side code, so it's working, but I'm leaving this out here in case others have a similar issue. Thank you for looking at it, at least.

Comment: You are using server-side code to update `Username`? That doesn't sound right. If you want all users' `Username` to equal their `Email` value, write a database UPDATE script to update all records at once. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HardCode Not for the update, just for the future. `Username` is allowed to change, since the `UserID` is the actual key, so the stored procedure updates 12 fields with 11 parameters: `Username` populates both `Username` and `Email` now. The RadGrid lists the records with `Email` as the user name from past programming, and the Edit function can update it, among other fields.

Comment: This is your first mention of a `UserID` field. Perhaps edit your question, rephrasing current state and desired state? It kind of seems like you want to hack a short-cut for using one field for another, where you should instead change your application without anything hack-like, to function according to the new requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256731/discussion-between-michael-foster-and-hardcode).